# Copy XLS values into text file which contains content

Tags: powershell, text, vbscript, replace, xls

I have an existing text file created in a certain format, so that my VBS program can read it and use the file as a data store to validate the similar values in my application.

I now wish to update this text file, from an XLS sheet, so that the text (which is tab separated), is not disturbed, but the individual values within it can be changed as corresponding to the XLS sheet.

Is there a way to accomplish this with VBS itself or using powershell / python on windows systems? I do not have access to a UNIX box, hence unable to use the sed-awk tools for doing this and also the *NIX tools will not be able to read a XLS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textstream object does not support to insert text. To do this in vbscript you have to read the text file, store it into an array, update the array (supposedly you have corresponding unique key fields) and write the complete text file from the array.